# Batch File Resume with Prewritten Arguments

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I have two batch files one batch files calls another. The one that calls the other is called install.bat, and the other controller.bat.

The contents of install.bat are as follows:

```
start controller.bat a.exe b.exe
```

Then the controller.bat file operates as such:

```
@echo off

:: Check if the first argument is passed
if "%~1"=="" (
    echo "No first argument passed"
) else (
    set first_arg=%~1
)

:: Check if the second argument is passed
if "%~2"=="" (
    echo "No second argument passed"
) else (
    set second_arg=%~2
    if not "%~1" == "" (
        set current=one
    ) else(
     echo twob >%~dp0current.txt
    )
)

call :Resume
goto %current%
goto :eof

:one
::Add script to Run key
reg add HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run /v %~n0 /d %~dpnx0 /f
echo two >%~dp0current.txt
echo -- Section one --
echo "update will start"
start /wait %second_arg%
echo "update done"
pause
shutdown -r -t 0
goto :eof

:two
echo three >%~dp0current.txt
echo -- Section two --
echo "updating now"
Start /wait %first_arg% 
echo "Update Finish"
pause
shutdown -r -t 0
goto :eof

:twob
reg add HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run /v %~n0 /d %~dpnx0 /f
echo three >%~dp0current.txt
echo -- Section two --
echo "updating now"
Start /wait %first_arg%
echo "Update Finish"
pause
shutdown -r -t 0
goto :eof

:three
::Remove script from Run key
reg delete HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run /v %~n0 /f
del %~dp0current.txt
echo -- Section three --
pause
goto :eof

:resume
if exist %~dp0current.txt (
    set /p current=<%~dp0current.txt
) else (
    set current=one
)
```

The problem it is not working well it jumps into twob and then straight to three. It is supposed to show the intermediate steps to a user to show the updates are occurring.

I am expecting it to be able to read if one argument is supplied let's say the second and not the first and still do the jumps to right labels. Right now, the labels are a bit mixed up when I supply both args %~1 and %~2.

Comment: Where an 'else' block is used, the `else` keyword, a separator and the opening parenthesis of the "else" block must be on the same physical line `) else (` - in the checking of the second argument (also a good idea to add `goto :eof` on the last line to make the code not-layout-dependent.

Comment: @Magoo What line number or line would be a good idea to add the eof? I fixed the else.

Comment: There must be a between after `else` & `(`. The space between `)` and `else` is not required, but omitting it is ugly.

Comment: You have `goto :eof` at the end of each routine, but not at the end of `:resume`. If you put `goto :eof` consistently at the end of each code segment, then you can re-arrange code segments as you will. It's really a matter of form - some people like to organise their routines in alphabetical order.